# Como crear un txt en android sdk 22 lolipop que sea accesible desde explorador de archivos

Tags: android, archivo, android-permissions, almacenamiento

Mi programa me permite guardar y recuperar un documento, pero este se guarda en un directorio que solo se pueden acceder a él si tengo el teléfono rooteado.

¿Cómo lo guardo en un directorio accesible como por ejemplo Documentos?

Lo quiero implementar para teléfonos con SDK 22 (Lolipop 5.1) en adelante, estoy usando Android Studio 3.0.1

Este es el código de main_activity.java

función que define si existe el documento

```
private boolean existeFile(String[] archivos,String archivo)
{
    for(int f=0;f<archivos.length;f++)
        if(archivo.equals(archivos[f]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

función que busca el documento

```
public void Buscar(View view)
{
    String[] archivos = fileList();
    String archivo = etArchivo.getText().toString();
    archivo = archivo.replace('/','-') + ".txt";

    //Código para recuperar el archivo de la MicroSD
    /*
    try{
        File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath(),archivo);
        if(file.exists()){
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fin);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String linea = br.readLine();
            String texto = "";
            while (linea != null){
                texto = texto + linea + "\n";
                linea = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            isr.close();
            etTexto.setText(texto);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo no existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.i("Agenda",e.toString());
    }*/

    //Código para recuperar el archivo de la memoria interna
    if(existeFile(archivos,archivo))
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader file = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(archivo));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
            String linea = br.readLine();
            String texto = "";
            while(linea != null)
            {
                texto += linea + "\n";
                linea = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            file.close();
            etTexto.setText(texto);
         }
         catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.i("Agenda",e.toString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo no existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

función que escribe en el documento

```
public void Grabar(View view)
{
    String archivo = etArchivo.getText().toString();
    archivo = archivo.replace('/','-') + ".txt";

    try
    {
        //Guardar en MicroSD
        /*File tarjeta = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(tarjeta.getAbsolutePath(),archivo);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
        osw.write(etTexto.getText().toString());
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();*/
        OutputStreamWriter file = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(archivo,MODE_PRIVATE));
        file.write(etTexto.getText().toString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        Log.i("Agenda",e.toString());
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,"Datos grabados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.LimpiarTextos();
}
```

Este es mi el contenido de mi manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.luisg.agenda">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Vista"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Agregue una respuesta solo quiero comentarte que si llamas el método con el parametro view: public void Grabar(View view)  seguramente lo estas llamando desde el layout mediante el método "android:onClick=Grabar" ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Como crear un archivo .txt que sea accesible desde explorador de archivos

> Mi programa me permite guardar y recuperar un documento, pero este se
> guarda en un directorio que solo se pueden acceder a él si tengo el
> teléfono rooteado.

en realidad simplemente debes obtener el path del directorio externo mediante:

[`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())

de esta forma se podra visualizar mediante el explorador de archivos sin necesidad de tener permisos "root".

También es necesario el permiso dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Este es un ejemplo de acuerdo a tu código:

```
  public void Grabar(View view) {
        
        String archivo = etArchivo.getText().toString();
        archivo = archivo.replace('/','-') + ".txt";

        //Obtiene ruta de sdcard
        File pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //agrega directorio /myFiles
        File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/myFiles/");
        //Si no existe la estructura, se crea usando mkdirs()
        appDirectory.mkdirs();
        //Crea archivo
        File saveFilePath = new File(appDirectory, archivo);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
            OutputStreamWriter file = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            file.write(etTexto.getText().toString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("Agenda",e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("Agenda",e.toString());
        }

        Toast.makeText(this,"Datos grabados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.LimpiarTextos();

    }
```

El archivo es creado en el almacenamiento externo y se puede visualizar :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

El método para leer el contenido de tu archivo también tendría que modificarse para leer el path donde se creo el archivo inicialmente,

Es importante mencionar que el nombre del archivo a buscar debe encontrarse en el array `archivos`, de otra forma no permitirá leer el contenido del archivo,

```
 if(existeFile(archivos,archivo))
    {
     ...
     ...
```

el código para leer el archivo sería:

```
   public void Buscar(View view)
    {
        String[] archivos = fileList();
        String archivo = etArchivo.getText().toString();
        archivo = archivo.replace('/','-') + ".txt";

 
        //Código para recuperar el archivo de la memoria interna
        if(existeFile(archivos,archivo))
        {
            try
            {
                //Obtiene ruta de sdcard
                File pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                //agrega directorio /myFiles
                File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "/myFiles/");
                //Si no existe la estructura, se crea usando mkdirs()
                appDirectory.mkdirs();
                //Crea archivo
                File saveFilePath = new File(appDirectory, archivo);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saveFilePath));
                String linea; // = br.readLine();
                String texto = "";
                while((linea  = br.readLine())!= null)
                {
                    texto += linea + "\n";
                }
                br.close();
                etTexto.setText(texto);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.i("Agenda",e.toString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"El archivo no existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probé tu respuesta, pero al parecer no crea el directorio "/myFiles" o guarda en Documents los txt que genera, ya no los puedo recuperar ni en el almacenamiento privado de la app. En manifest, agregué los permisos     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: En el almacenamiento "privado" no es opción ya que solo podrás acceder si tu dispositivo es "root".  Solo se necesita WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE el otro permiso es inherente, tu dispositivo debe ser sistema operativo menor a 6.0 de otra forma los permisos deben ser pedidos manualmente, probé el código ve en donde me creo el folder en la imagen. @Kuroi

Comment: Cierto, o probé en mi celular con Nougat, le di permisos desde el menú del sistema y me crea el directorio con su documento, ahora con un dispositivo emulado con lolipop, me crea el documento, pero no lo puedo recuperar, por lo que cuando lo guardo, lo sobreescribo

Comment: ok ya tienes tu "Lollipop emulado" ok comentas que no lo puedes recuperar, en que método se realiza eso? @Kuroi de hecho es solo cambiar la obtención de la ruta mediante Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: en mi función                                                                                  
    private boolean existeFile(String[] archivos,String archivo)
   {
        for(int f=0;f<archivos.length;f++)
           if(archivo.equals(archivos[f]))
               return true;
        return false;
    }

Comment: Primeramente en el array archivos debe estar el nombre del archivo si no se encuentra, no entraría a buscar el archivo y su contenido. Veo que tienes varios problemas, cuando uses  br.readLine() se supone leer una linea de contenido, si lo usas más de una ocasión no se leera correctamente la información dentro del archivo, agrego una solución a tu método

Comment: Y si solo quiero agregar contenido en la función grabar sin que haya sobreescritura?

Comment: Para evitar sobreescribir el texto, a la hora de escribir le añadí un true

Comment: @Kuroi exacto, ya que con esto se habilita el "append", saludos!